Probability density function of the sufficient statistic
I am studying Hogg and McKean's "Introduction to Mathematical Statistics" and the following is a theorem whose proof he has asked in his exercise.
Exercise 7.5.8. If $X_1, X_2, \cdots , X_n$ is a random sample from a distribution that has a pdf which is a regular case of the exponential class, show that the pdf of $Y_1 = \sum_1^n K(X_i)$ is of the form $f_{Y_1} (y_1; \theta) = R(y_1) \exp[p(\theta)y_1 + nq(\theta)].$
Hint: Let $Y_2 = X_2,\cdots,Y_n = X_n$ be $n − 1$ auxiliary random variables. Find the joint pdf of $Y_1,Y_2,\cdots,Y_n$ and then the marginal pdf of $Y_1$.
Definition 7.5.1. Define $f(x;\theta)$ as
$$f(x,\theta) = \exp[p(\theta)K(x) + H(x) + q(\theta)], ~~ x \in S$$
and zero elsewhere (here $S$ is the support). The the pdf of this form is said to be a member of the regular exponential class of probability density or mass functions if
(1) $S$, the support of $X$, does not depend upon $\theta$
(2) $p(\theta)$ is a nontrivial continuous function of $\theta \in \Omega$
(3) Finally,
(a) if $X$ is a continuous random variable, then each of $K'(x) \neq 0$ and $H(x)$ is a continuous function of $x \in S$,
(b) if $X$ is a discrete random variable, then $K(x)$ is a nontrivial function of $x \in S$.
My thoughts: Honestly I have no idea how to proceed especially given that he has asked us to start with joint pdf of the set of random variables $\{Y_i\}_1^n$. The set of random variables $\{Y_i\}_2^n$ are all mutually independent so their joint pdf is easily found. But then $Y_1$ is surely not independent of any of these random variables. How then do we find the joint pdf of $\{Y_i\}_1^n$? All we know about $Y_1$ (at least at this stage in the text) is that it is a complete sufficient statistic for $\theta$.
I went back in the text to see if there is any material that has information about how to find this joint pdf. The closest I could find is Neyman's theorem (Theorem $7.2.1$ of the text) which basically says that if $Y_1$ is a sufficient statistic of $\theta$, then the likelihood function of $\{X_i\}_1^n$ is a product of the pdf of $Y_1$ and some other function of the samples $\{x_i\}_1^n$ that is independent of $\theta$. That does not seem to be of much help.
If we were to use his hint, we would have to start with
$$F_{Y_1,Y_2,\cdots,Y_n}(y_1,y_2,\cdots,y_n) = P(Y_1\leq y_1,Y_2\leq y_2,\cdots,Y_n\leq y_n)$$ where $Y_2 = X_2,\cdots,Y_n = X_n$ and are hence mutually independent, but then $Y_1=\sum_1^n K(X_i)$. Not sure how to proceed from here.
I'd greatly appreciate it if you can please help me figure out how to use his hint to solve this problem.

You may find section 2.7 helpful.

The transformation $g(x_1, \ldots, x_n) = (\sum_{i=1}^n K(x_i), x_2, \ldots, x_n)$ has Jacobian
$$\begin{vmatrix}
K'(x_1) & K'(x_2) & K'(x_3) & \cdots & K'(x_n)
\\
0 & 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0
\\
0 & 0 & 1 & \cdots & 0
\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots
\\
0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 1
\end{vmatrix} = |K'(x_1)|.$$
We can use this to do a change of variables for the densities.
\begin{align}
&f_{Y_1, \ldots, Y_n}(\sum_{i=1}^n K(x_i), x_2, \ldots, x_n) |K'(x_1)|
\\
&= f_{X_1, \ldots, X_n}(x_1, \ldots, x_n)
\\
&= \exp\left(\sum_{i=1}^n [p(\theta) K(x_i) + H(x_i) ]\right) \exp(nq(\theta))
\end{align}
Rewriting in terms of $y_1, \ldots, y_n$ yields
\begin{align}
&f_{Y_1, \ldots, Y_n}(y_1, \ldots, y_n)
\\
&= |K'(y_1 - \sum_{i=2}^n K(y_i))|^{-1} \exp\left(p(\theta)(y_1 - \sum_{i=2}^n K(y_i)) + H(K^{-1}(y_1 - \sum_{i=2}^n K(y_i)) + \sum_{i=2}^n [p(\theta)K(y_i) + H(y_i)]\right)\exp(nq(\theta))
\\
&= |K'(y_1 - \sum_{i=2}^n K(y_i))|^{-1} \exp\left(p(\theta)y_1  + H(K^{-1}(y_1 - \sum_{i=2}^n K(y_i)) + \sum_{i=2}^n H(y_i)\right)\exp(nq(\theta))
\end{align}
Integrating over $y_2, \ldots, y_n$ yields
\begin{align}
&f_{Y_1}(y_1)
\\
&= \int f_{Y_1, \ldots, Y_n}(y_1, \ldots, y_n) \, dy_2 \cdots dy_n
\\
&=\exp\left(p(\theta)y_1 + n q(\theta)\right)
\int
|K'(y_1 - \sum_{i=2}^n K(y_i))|^{-1} \exp\left(H(K^{-1}(y_1 - \sum_{i=2}^n K(y_i)) + \sum_{i=2}^n H(y_i)\right)
\, dy_2 \cdots dy_n
\\
&= R(y_1) \exp\left(p(\theta)y_1 + n q(\theta)\right).
\end{align}
The last step comes from observing the last integral is a function of $y_1$ and doesn't depend on $\theta$.

Thanks for the solution. Looks like all we need to do was to plough through the standard change of variable path. I greatly appreciate you typing out the entire proof for me.
